# R - How to rotate/interchange predictors in a regression model (a not-stepwise approach)

Tags: r, regression, data-modeling

A given dataset has a range of predictors that should be used one by one in a simple (although multivariate) regression model. I am unable to grasp if I need something that loops through the (name of the) predictors or something like `lapply()` would suffice.

Creating a function needs an argument before it creates an output, but I wouldn't know how to incorporate a for loop in a given model formula.

```
Some data
---
df <- data.frame(y1=runif(100,1,10),
    y2=runif(100,1,10),
    x1= runif(100,1,5),
    x2= runif(100,1,5), 
    x3= runif(100,1,5))

Y = cbind( df$y1 , df$y2 )
```

I have a feeling it is something in the lines of this:

```
list_pred <- for ( x in 1:colnames(pred)) {
  print(paste(x))
}
```

But the `for` loop doesn't  really wants to work along. So it makes me think that I might have to create a function that incorporates the `lm()` argument as well.

```
not_stepwise <- matrix( 0 , predictor , 1 ) # pre-allocation?
for (x in 1:predictor) {
 lm.dd <- lm( Y ~ [x] , data = df ] )
}
```

But at this point I am not sure where to look for, Google nor StackOverflow has a somewhat extensive information on this (except for the statistical implication, but I have that covered).

**Update**: To clarify, I am looking for an overview of R² values of the models themselves (and/or sig. predictors) to ascertain if that model would even have a significant predictor or not, e.g. a meaningful model.

**Update 2**: How my data set looks (without DVs)

```
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  35 variables:
 $ Minuten             : int  72 30 102 212 37 57 120 146 143 189 ...
 $ Teamsize            : int  3 3 4 3 2 4 5 6 5 3 ...
 $ Exp                 : num  6.67 6.67 5.5 5.33 10.5 ...
 $ Chirurg1            : int  10 10 1 2 4 2 3 3 2 9 ...
 $ Chirurg2            : int  11 11 2 NA NA NA NA NA 9 2 ...
 $ NG                  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ NG.Ratio            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Specialisme         : int  2 2 1 3 1 3 1 1 3 3 ...
 $ Observaties         : int  43 21 55 132 22 90 90 64 100 129 ...
 $ UniqueCom           : int  9 6 9 12 4 9 9 12 16 12 ...
 $ G.Ratio             : num  0.333 0.667 0.25 0.667 0.5 ...
 $ Bewustwording       : int  1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 ...
 $ Confrontatie        : int  0 1 0 2 0 0 0 1 1 2 ...
 $ Confrontatie.Outside: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Coordinerend        : int  1 3 6 17 2 4 10 6 14 9 ...
 $ Delegerend          : int  6 3 2 22 0 9 6 1 15 11 ...
 $ Goedaardig          : int  3 0 5 4 0 7 3 2 9 1 ...
 $ Grappig             : int  0 1 0 0 0 2 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ Hofmaken            : int  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 2 1 0 ...
 $ Instruerend         : int  9 0 7 13 0 7 3 9 7 13 ...
 $ Onderwijzend        : int  6 5 3 21 9 2 14 5 8 22 ...
 $ Ontbindend          : int  1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ Protest             : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ Reactief            : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ Respons.Negatief    : int  0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 ...
 $ Respons.Neutraal    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 ...
 $ Respons.Positief    : int  1 0 1 2 1 1 0 1 2 8 ...
 $ Sign.out            : int  1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 ...
 $ Time.out            : int  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Volgzaam            : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ Vragend             : int  0 0 0 3 0 0 1 0 1 1 ...
 $ rank_sum            : int  27 11 24 80 12 33 37 25 58 65 ...
 $ rank_sum.60s        : num  0.375 0.367 0.235 0.377 0.324 ...
 $ ranking             : int  43 56 46 11 55 37 35 45 21 17 ...
 $ ranking.60s         : int  30 34 72 29 49 1 58 92 21 41 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

A first simple solution

```
# Generate a dataset
X <- data.frame(matrix(runif(1000), ncol=20))
y <- rnorm(nrow(X))
dts <- data.frame(y, X)

lms <- vector(ncol(X), mode="list")
k <- 1
for (x in names(X)) {
   # Create formula with the k-th x variabile
   frml <- as.formula(paste0("y ~", x))
   # Use the formula in a linear model
   lms[[k]] <- lm(frml, data=dts)
   k <- k+1
}
# This is the output of the linear model with the 15-th x variable
summary(lms[[15]])
# A matrix with R-squared and adjusted R-squared
r2 <- function(x) c(summary(x)$r.squared, summary(x)$adj.r.squared)
t(sapply(lms, r2))
```

A more elegant and flexible solution

```
R2 <- function(x, data) {
     frml <- as.formula(paste0("y ~", paste(unlist(x), collapse="+"))) 
     lmfit <- lm(frml, data=data)
     lmsum <- summary(lmfit)
     data.frame(R2=lmsum$r.squared, adj.R2=lmsum$adj.r.squared)
}
R2 <- Vectorize(R2, "x")

# The R-squared for all the univariate models
R2(names(X), dts)

# The R-squared for all the bivariate models 
k <- 2   
xcouples <- apply(combn(names(X), k), 2, list)
names(xcouples) <- lapply(xcouples, function(x) paste(unlist(x), collapse="_"))
t(R2(xcouples, dts))
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Only I forgot that I need to check R²-values, is there a way to make a list that has model and R² as a result of the ```for``` loop?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, in your most above example the matrix returns ```NULL```. ```summary(lm_dd$r.squared[[15]])``` also returns ```NULL```, whilst without ```$r.squared``` it works perfectly fine. 

Your second example gives ```'data' must be a data.frame, not a matrix or an array```. Your ```X```corresponds with a subset of mine without the DVs, I changed some of the names in order to make it work in my script but to no avail.

Comment: But it should still be a data.frame, your example with simulated data works perfect tho

Comment: @fleems The  right syntax is `summary(lm_dd)$r.squared`.

Comment: @fleems Please, share the ouput of your complete dataset  with `dput(df)` using for example pastebin.com

Answer (score 1):

To find the all possible regression outputs including multiple combinations in your data set, the codes below may help.

```
# To find all combinations of the predictors.

predictors <- names(df)[-1]
all_comb <- sapply(seq(predictors) ,function(i) {t(combn(predictors,i))})


# Calculating the regression outputs and putting into a list called result.

result <- list()

    for(x in 1:length(all_comb)){

        for(i in 1:nrow(all_comb[[x]])) {

            name <- paste(all_comb[[x]][i,], collapse = '_')
            group <- paste0("Y ~ ",paste0(all_comb[[x]][i,],collapse =" + "))
            result[[name]] <- lm(group, data =df )          

        }

     }
```

Calling `result` gives,

```
...
  ...

$x1_x3

Call:
lm(formula = group, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1           x3  
     6.6647      -0.3864      -0.0954  


$x2_x3

Call:
lm(formula = group, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x2           x3  
     5.3037       0.1438      -0.1459  


$x1_x2_x3

Call:
lm(formula = group, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1           x2           x3  
    6.16101     -0.39160      0.15794     -0.07796
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(Y=runif(100,1,10),
    x1= runif(100,1,5),
    x2= runif(100,1,5), 
    x3= runif(100,1,5))
```

Comment: I wasn't looking for all combinations, but it might be interesting from a data driven point of view. We can always set up a new experiment. Would you have a solution on how to create a list that shows the models and their R² values,  in the frame of all possible combinations?

Comment: @fleems Instead of  `result[[name]] <- lm(group, data =df )`  use `result[[name]] <- summary(lm(group, data =df ))$r.squared`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, when running your function (which is very clean) I do get ```Error in model.frame.default(formula = group, data = df, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : variable lengths differ (found for 'x1')```. I only changed the subset (your *df*) to my subset which is a data.frame. I removed the ```[-1]``` since my Y wasn't in the first column and running ```all_comb <- sapply(seq(predictors) ,function(i) {t(combn(predictors,i))})``` doesn't continue, as if I am missing a bracket or something

Comment: The dependent variable which is `Y` is assigned at this part: `group <- paste0("Y ~ ",paste0(all_comb[[x]][i,],collapse =" + "))`. So have a look if your data includes a `Y` as a dependent variable. Of course you can change it as you wish. The error you got basically saying the number of rows are not the same.So somehow the  `nrow(Y)` and `nrow(x1)` , `nrow(x2)` ... are not matching!